# Acquiring list of mayors from every city in USA

Tags: united-states, parties

Hopefully this question isn't off-topic. I've been trying to locate a comprehensive list of every mayor currently in office within the United States and I'm not finding much other than junk like "[Current Mayors of the top 100 cities in the United States](https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_current_mayors_of_the_top_100_cities_in_the_United_States)".

I'm looking for a resource that would contain all **16,374** mayors currently holding office and their party designation. Other than finding a site that charges money for this information I haven't seen anything while searching. Is there a free resource that is available for this type of stuff, or place where I can build a large query based on public datasets? Thank you.

Comment: I very much doubt it, to be honest.  That's a lot of mayors to keep track of, especially to not charge anyone for.

Comment: Where did you get the number 16,374? There are 19,495 incorporated municipalities in the US. The US Census Bureau defines a city as any municipality with a population over 2,500. However, each state has its own definition for a city. For example, in Connecticut, cities are only incorporated by an act of the state legislature. In Massachusetts, cities are defined by their form of government. Furthermore, I grew up in a _town_ that had a mayor, and not all cities have a mayor.

Comment: I would have recommended scraping this information of out Wikipedia, but I just proved myself wrong.

Comment: Plus, not all mayors have listed political affiliations.

Comment: @AndrewRay: Thanks very much for your help! I got the number from [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mwJecZ-zhFQJ:https://lists.nextmark.com/market%3Fpage%3Dorder/online/datacard%26id%3D203682), so I guess that's not quite accurate.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane: I was thinking that would be somewhat straightforward as well, but apparently not.

Comment: @jeffronicus: Interesting, I did not know that.